# How to Work around a XAML Styler Bug?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to underline the first letter of a button's name.

```
<Button.Content>
<TextBlock>
<Underline>N</Underline>ame
</TextBlock>
</Button.Content>
```

However, when I right click the code, then click Beautify XAML, the code appears as this:

```
<Button.Content>
<TextBlock>
<Underline>N</Underline>
ame
</TextBlock>
</Button.Content>
```

Separating the N and ame into two lines adds a space between the two strings, like this: N ame.

I like the Styler, but this is really annoying.

Comment: Are you abusing a `TextBlock` to create something like a `Label` (which has access key support)?

Comment: I used InputBindings to bind the shortcut to the command. I all I wanted is a simple underline get the attention of users.

Comment: Why not use [`AccessText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.accesstext.aspx) then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This seems to work, kind of funny looking though

```
<Button.Content>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="N" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
        <TextBlock Text="ame" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button.Content>
```

Comment: The formatter will probably push that so a new line as well (which will also create a space in the output).

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use the underscore to show an alt hotkey, this is the way:

```
<Button Content="_Name"/>
```

That will show the underlined N when the user pushes Alt, as it should.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work. Using <AccessText Text="_Name" /> was nessacry.